# Why Brauer-Severi varieties over number fields satisfy the Hasse principle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If I understand correctly, a Brauer-Severi variety is supposed to be a variety $X/k$ such that it becomes isomorphic over $\overline{k}$ to some projective space $\mathbb{P}_{k}^{n}$. When $k$ is a number field, and if we suppose that $X(k_{v})\neq{\emptyset}$ for every place $v$ of $k$, then $X(k)\neq{\emptyset}$.

I can't find the reference where this statement is proved, so I would appreciate it if you could tell me where exactly I can read the proof. Otherwise, I tried to prove it by using three facts: 1) the set of $k$-isomorphic Brauer-Severi varieties of dimension $n-1$ is parametrized by $H^{1}(k,\mathrm{PGL}_{n}(k))$, 2) The set of equivalence classes of central simple algebras $A$ over $k$ of dimension $n^{2}$ is parametrized again by $H^{1}(k,\mathrm{PGL}_{n}(k))$, 3) If $A$ is a central simple $k$-algebra of dimension $n$ such that $A\otimes_{k}k_{v}\cong{\mathrm{Mat}_{n}(k_{v})}$ as $k$-algebras and for every place $v$ of $k$, then $A\cong{A\otimes_{k}k}\cong{\mathrm{Mat}_{n}(k)}$ (this is supposed to be another example of the Hasse principle and it's called Albert-Brauer-Hasse-Noether theorem according to wikipedia...).

I have the feeling that somehow I need to use these 3 results, but I can't figure out the way to do it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The Hasse principle for central simple algebras says that the map

$$H^1(k, PGL_n(k)) \to \prod_v H^1(k_v, PGL_n(k_v))$$

detects $0$ in the sense that the preimage of $0$ is again $0$. The Hasse principle for Brauer-Severi varieties says the same thing.

Comment: Probably it is worth mentioning that a Severi-Brauer variety is trivial if and only if it has a point.